# Slow/laggy system on a mid-end PC

Tags: drivers, ati, kde, performance

I just moved from Windows 8.1 3 days ago (which was running very good in terms of performance and multi-tasking).

I'm using Ubuntu 15.04 with KDE Plasma 5.3 installed and the system isn't fast as it should be.

My specs are:

Gigabyte G41MT-S2P

Intel Core2Duo E7500 2.93GHZ

AMD 5570 1GB DDR3

4GB Kingstone RAM

It lags when I've simple things opened like Chrome and VLC.

eg: hovering over "Leave" in the application launcher takes ~2 seconds to show the Log off, shutdown, and other options. and Dolphin lags every now and then..Some pop-up messages take time to load.

the thing is: when I take a look at KSysGuard it shows only ~20% of the CPU and ~2.5 GB of memory is used (and ~no swap used)..What the heck is wrong?

I heard that it might be a problem with the AMD driver, but I'm using the prosperity one from "Additional Drivers" on Ubuntu.

Comment: > KDE Plasma 5.3, no GPU(?), Core2Duo -> try XUbuntu

Comment: The reason I went to Linux is KDE so no KDE no Linux for me.

Comment: I'd say that KDE, Unity / Gnome and maybe some more of those are GFX-intensive and "needs" more than a basic Gfx-setup.

Comment: Use `top` in a terminal window (or is it konsole?).

Comment: [top](http://i.imgur.com/yti2JPh.png)

Comment: Please add the output of `cat /proc/sys/vm/swappiness`.

Comment: Do you run a dedicated GPU? Core2duo is not mid end :)

Comment: It's 60. @the_Seppi

Comment: Yes, It's a dedicated AMD 5570 like I said. @davidbaumann

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
vm.swappiness=0
```

to the end of `/etc/sysctl.conf` and reboot or set swappiness to zero. This way you will not hit disk swap until you run out of RAM.

You can also try disabling Akonadi:

https://userbase.kde.org/Akonadi#Disabling_the_Akonadi_subsystem

http://www.my-guides.net/en/guides/linux/how-to-disable-nepomuk-strigi-and-akonadi-in-kde4 (applicable to KDE5)

Comment: I've just uninstalled Ubuntu and installed Kubuntu.Looking good 'till now..Will try this if I experience any lag.Thanks!

Comment: It made the lag even worse!

Comment: That's strange. Can you check how much RAM is used in `ksysguard`'s second tab?

Comment: 2.2GB of 3.9GB and 0 of 8GB swap.

Comment: Ok, maybe it's a video driver problem or HDD being too old then? IDK.

Comment: I'm using the prosperity one from "Additional Drivers" on Ubuntu.
I tried installing the one from AMD website (by building a .deb package) but it made the system unbootable. and I don't think there's anything wrong with the HDD.

Comment: IT IS GETTING WORSE.
Now launching Chrome takes ~7+ seconds!